# How do you insert multiple unique records into another table based off of individual rows in a starting table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, while-loop, fetch

How do you iterate through a table row by row, and insert entries based off of those individual rows, into another table in MSSQL?

Comment: Usually if you start thinking about a problem by saying "row by row" you're thinking about it wrong. However you need to be more explicit in what you actually mean. Can you show us a few individual rows in the starting table, and what rows you want inserted into the new table based off of that, including any foreseeable edge cases or issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you MUST go row-by-row, you'd be declaring and using a cursor.  It's usually not a good idea, and I'd be curious why you need to do so.  The tags on your question (fetch, while) imply that you already have some clue about cursors.  The general form looks something like:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @num INT; -- other columns
```

-- EDIT added LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY per comment below

```
DECLARE excruciatingly_slow CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT 1  --this is just a sample, your query (which you might want to supply) will differ
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2;

OPEN excruciatingly_slow;    
FETCH NEXT FROM excruciatingly_slow
    INTO @num -- other variables
    ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS > -1
    BEGIN
        -- Do something here
        INSERT destination_table
            (    column_list -- other columns...
            )
        SELECT @num -- other columns
            ;

        FETCH NEXT FROM excruciatingly_slow
            INTO @num-- other variables
            ;
    END;
CLOSE excruciatingly_slow;
DEALLOCATE excruciatingly_slow;
```

In most cases this would be better done with the INSERT...SELECT... constructs suggested by the other replies.  There is a homework tag if this is course-related.  I'm having trouble thinking of a case where a single insert would be better served by a cursor.

Comment: If you're doing it for reading only, the cursor is probably better off defined as `DECLARE slightly_faster_than_excruciatingly_slow CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR <...query...>`. I've demonstrated in my bad habits to kick presentation that adding those attributes can improve a cursor's performance by 50-60% or more.

Comment: @AaronBertrand:  good point, and SET NOCOUNT ON would likely be a good idea too.  But if performance is an issue why use a cursor?

Comment: To be honest, you can't always avoid a cursor. So I do my best to encourage best practices, even when some best practices are being ignored. "I don't always use a cursor. But when I do, I use local static read only forward only. Stay performant, my friends."

Comment: True, and I've updated the code accordingly.  Still I feel a bit like a worker at a suicide hotline who's been asked "I hear Xanax makes you naseous, should I use Vicodin?"

Comment: I think a better analogy is if you have to go to Siberia you should go by helicopter instead of dogsled.

Comment: Thank you to Jason for the quick answer. I was never able to find a great answer on the Google machine, so I decided this was something that should belong to stack overflow. The real situation I had to deal with was generating sets of unique serial numbers (a few hundred rows) that were related to another table of products. The tricky part was there is no sequential index (1,2,3,4) as the result set may have differing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
INSERT INTO <table> ( <columns> )
SELECT FROM <source_table> ( <matching number columns> )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
insert into Table2 (columnA, ColumnB)
select ColumnA, ColumnB from Table1
where ColumnA = 'Blah'
```

Basically you are doing a select on one table and inserting it into another table

Answer (score 0):

you can use `case` for that:

```
insert into destinationTable
    select case id when 1 then ...
           end
    from sourceTable
```